# Trying to use selenium on python to change the value of hidden input or sendkeys to a text field

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to sendkeys to a specific text field, but it won't send anything. I suspect its because of the html code load-remove. Basically, I input some text, a dropdown window appears, I then am supposed to select the input. I notice that the input type "hidden" changes value after I select my choice. Would it be possible to change the hidden value directly with selenium? I have included imgur links to show the process. Ignore the last picture, I have included my new updated code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFmja.jpg

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


PATH = r"C:\Users\KELLY\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://xxxx.xyz.com/")

inputName = driver.find_element_by_id("Email")
inputName.send_keys("some-user-key")

inputPW = driver.find_element_by_id("Password")
inputPW.send_keys("some-password")
inputPW.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

addEntry = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'btnAddCEntry')))
addEntry.click()

inputClient = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'txtClientAccount')))
inputClient.click()
inputClient.send_keys("some-client-key")
```

This is the html code

```
<div class="col-sm-8 pad-l-0">
                                <input type="text" name="client" id="txtClientAccount" class="form-control required nonsubmittextboxauto drpProg ui-autocomplete-input valid" placeholder="Type Client Name" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="txtClientAccount-error" part="John Doe><span id="txtClientAccount-error" class="error" style="display: none;"></span>
                                <span id="fAccountClient" class="error accessibility-hide"></span>
                                <input type="hidden" name="ClientId" id="hdnEmpClientId" class="clshdn" value="15084">
                                <div class="load-spinner" id="dvSpinnerClientAccount" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>
                                <div class="load-remove" id="dvRemoveEmpAccount" style="display: block;"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>
                            </div>
```

Thats under one tab, then theres like more functions right under it, I am assuming these functions are the ones that are ruining my sendkeys() input.

Comment: You shared the email & password for that website in your post! If those are the real credentials, you might want to change them!

Comment: @PApostol, thanks man sorry LOL